# TFTP Server for Windows

Tags: software-development, tftp-server

I need a TFTP server to run on Windows 7. 
A google search reveals amongst others:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/tftp-server/
http://www.solarwinds.com/products/freetools/free_tftp_server.aspx

I haven't heard of these before (maybe because I have been linux-hosted previously).

Are they any good? What other TFTP server options are available?

**Background**: This is required for a single developer to support PXE boot of various development targets, and will be used in conjunction with a DHCP server, yet to be determined. A tool which can perform both roles, to act as a complete PXE solution would also be an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Trivial File Transfer Protocol (TFTP) is a simple, lock-step, file transfer protocol which allows a client to get from or put a file onto a remote host. One of its primary uses is in the early stages of nodes booting from a Local Area Network.

Since you have asked for a apllication which acts as a **PXE-Preboot eXecution Environment**  I suggest that you look into [Serva](http://www.vercot.com/~serva/default.html),It is an **Automated PXE Server Solution Accelerator**
based on an all-in-one portable multi-server engine.It bundles on a single exe all of the underlying server protocols and services required by the most complex PXE network boot/install scenarios simultaneously delivering Windows and non-Windows resources.

- HTTP server
- FTP server
- TFTP server
- TFTP client
- DHCP server
- proxyDHCP server 1
- BINL server 2
- DNS server
- SNTP server
- SYSLOG server

  1. *PXE DHCP service that does not require altering your current DHCP*
  2. *The application does not require installation, It does not require 
     Internet connection, it does not save keys on your Windows registry,
     and it can be used right away*

Note:Pls refer the documentation for further instruction which will help you to set-up this :) [serva Instructions](http://www.vercot.com/~serva/an/WindowsPXE1.html)

[image: Screenshot]

[image]

> Compatible for Windows 7 - Starter/Home Basic/Home
>   Premium/Professional/Enterprise/Ultimate (x86/64)

**Hope my answer helps!**

Comment: Ohh, I like this. Some of the configuration is a bit simplistic, especially on the DHCP where it would be good to provide client-specific configuration, but this is pretty good for simple setups

Comment: The free version also has to be restarted after 50 minutes.