# Free TFTP Server for Windows 8

Tags: windows, gratis, tftp-server

I'm looking for a [TFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_File_Transfer_Protocol) server that is:

1. Free and legal to use at my workplace (i.e. "free for personal use" won't work)
2. Runs on Windows, including 8.1

I'll use this server at work to transfer boot images to and from Cisco switches.

I already found [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16480/tftp-server-for-windows) but the accepted (and only) answer recommends a PXE Server solution.  I also have tried [FileZilla](http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/) but apparently it's a strictly FTP server, not TFTP.

Comment: May be this [TFTP Server for Windows](http://tftp-server-for-windows.en.lo4d.com/) but not sure.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately that TFTP server's license is not free (it's Shareware/Trialware)

Comment: use [hk-tftp-server](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hk-tftp-server/) free
powerful
fast
secure
easy to use webpage link : https://sourceforge.net/projects/hk-tftp-server/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tftpd32](http://tftpd32.jounin.net/) meets your specifications.  According to the program description:

> Tftpd32 is a free, opensource IPv6 ready application which includes DHCP, TFTP, DNS, SNTP and Syslog servers as well as a TFTP client.

32-bit and 64-bit versions are available [here](http://tftpd32.jounin.net/tftpd32_download.html).  There is a standalone program or a version that can be run as a Windows service.

The [license](http://tftpd32.jounin.net/tftpd32_license.html) is free for use in all circumstances:

> The Licensor hereby grants You a world-wide, royalty-free, non-exclusive, sub-licensable licence [sic] to do the following...use the [software] in any circumstance and for all usage.

I have successfully used Tftpd32.exe on Windows 8.1 Pro to transfer files via TFTP to Cisco switches.